# Generic object inside method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have some doubts about generic object and I don't know if my idea can be implemented easily...

I have objects that implement the same interface, so the methods are almost equals besides the main object like the code below:

```
public bool Func1 (Bitmap img)
{
   Obj1                 treatments    = new Obj1 ();
   List<UnmanagedImage> unmanagedList = treatments.ExtractLetters(img);

   // Check image treatments
   if (!treatments.WasSuccessful)
      return false

   return true
}

public bool Func2 (Bitmap img)
{
   Obj2                 treatments    = new Obj2 ();
   List<UnmanagedImage> unmanagedList = treatments.ExtractLetters(img);

   // Check image treatments
   if (!treatments.WasSuccessful)
      return false

   return true
}
```

In this case, I don't want to duplicate the code. Is there any easy way to make this Obj1 and Obj2 generic? Because I could write only one function, and then the function could do a cast in the object, because the rest is the same.

Thank you!

Comment: Do `Obj1` and `Obj2` have a common ancestor class (other than `System.Object`) or implement a common interface which has the `ExtractLetters()` method and `WasSuccessful` property?

Comment: Yep... they implement the same interface with the same methods =)

Comment: then dasblinkenlight nailed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is - assuming that all `Treatments` implement a common interface `ITreatments` that provides `ExtractLetters` and `WasSuccessful`, you can do this:

```
interface ITreatments {
    List<UnmanagedImage> ExtractLetters(Bitmap img);
    bool WasSuccessful {get;}
}

public bool Func<T>(Bitmap img) where T : new, ITreatments
{
    T treatments    = new T();
    List<UnmanagedImage> unmanagedList = treatments.ExtractLetters(img);
    return treatments.WasSuccessful;
}
```

Now you can call this function as follows:

```
if (Func<Obj1>(img)) {
    ...
}
if (Func<Obj2>(img)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you dude! Appreciate your help! I did it! Now it's working!!

Answer (score 2):

Only if `Obj1` and `Obj2` either implement an interface or inherit a base class that defines `ExtractLetters` and `WasSuccessful`.  Otherwise they are unrelated methods that happen to have the same name.

If there is an interface or base class you could do:

```
public bool Func1<T>(Bitmap img) where T: ITreatments, new()
{
   T treatments = new T();
   List<UnmanagedImage> unmanagedList = treatments.ExtractLetters(img);

   // Check image treatments
   if (!treatments.WasSuccessful)
      return false

   return true
}
```